# DAG based script execution scheduler/planner with GUI; similar to airbnb's airflow or BODS or Informatica

Tags: linux, python, shell-scripting, scheduling

We're looking for a GUI based execution scheduler/planner (or whatever it is called) to run various daily scripts and applications with dependencies. We'd like it to run on a headless Linux distro, and being able to connect to it using a local client or web interface.

What we've found thus far is airbnb's airflow project:

- http://nerds.airbnb.com/airflow/

What else exists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several workflow planners similar to Airflow. Some are:

- Spotify's [Luigi](https://github.com/spotify/luigi)
- [Mario](https://github.com/intentmedia/mario)  - A Scala version of Luigi
- [Ruigi](https://github.com/kirillseva/ruigi)  - Pipelining software for R

I have used both Luigi and Airflow. Airflow felt really nice, especially with nice, polished UI and the task history features.

Below is a screen shot of an example of a successfully run Airflow pipeline:
[image]

Comment: If you don't mind can you look at my question on [SO on airflow scheduling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33126159/airflow-not-scheduling-correctly-python) I just can't seem to find an answer .thanks and sorry if I disturbed you

Comment: @VigneshKalai I'm sorry, I am not well versed with Airflow.  We use Luigi in our architecture.  I used Airflow just for experimentation.

Comment: it is a small program it is just that the schedule interval is not correct .I thought you could clear the problem Thanks any ways Jalem Raj Rohit